# Question about Tidy

Tags: ide, geany

I just installed Geany IDE
When I tried to compile HTML file I got error
/bin/sh: 1: tidy: not found

Can someone help

Comment: the tidy project page is at http://tidy.sourceforge.net/   Source: http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/

Answer (score 1):

Similar trouble can get solved by typing

```
$ tidy --help
The program 'tidy' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install tidy
```

... to get a hint on which packages might come into question. If there are several suggested ones, then look them up (google).

The " --help" makes MOST software respond with a first level of information. If that appears, then "tidy" would probably been in a place that the "caller software" did/does not know about, another possible cause for similar problems (hint; add to $PATH)

Answer (score 0):

Run this in a terminal to install tidy:

```
sudo apt-get install tidy
```

then you are able to compile (<kbd>F8</kbd>) html files in Geany.

If you want to run them in the browser press <kbd>F5</kbd>.